# Why does does my client only show 1 digit of a factorial when the server sent the value via a socket connection?

Tags: c#, sockets

Client:

```
while (true)
{
    input = Console.ReadLine();
    if (input == "exit")
        break;
    server.SendTo(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(input), Remote);

    data = new byte[1024];
    recv = server.ReceiveFrom(data, ref Remote);
    stringData = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, recv);
    Console.WriteLine("{0}! là: {1}", input, stringData);
}
Console.WriteLine("Dang dong client");
server.Close();
```

Server:

```
while (true)
{
    int giaithualap(int n)
    {
        int giai_thua = 1;
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
            giai_thua *= i;
        return giai_thua;
    }

    data = new byte[1024];
    recv = newsock.ReceiveFrom(data, ref Remote);
    string a = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, recv);
    Console.WriteLine("Nhan tu : {0} so {1}  ", Remote.ToString(), a);
    int tong = giaithualap(int.Parse(a));
    Console.WriteLine("{0} so {1} giai thua la {2}", Remote.ToString(), a, tong);
    data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes( tong.ToString());
    newsock.SendTo(data, 0, recv, SocketFlags.None, Remote);
}
```

If you input a number which had 1 digit of factorial it will be fine, but a number with 2 digit of factorial or higher it will only show the first digit of that number.

[It only show the first digit of the factorial](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8gA4l.png)

Answer (score 1):

The error is in this line of your server code:

```
newsock.SendTo(data, 0, recv, SocketFlags.None, Remote);
```

You are sending `recv` bytes, which is how many bytes you *received* (in your example, simply 1 digit), not how many you want to send (2 digits). Change that to:

```
newsock.SendTo(data, 0, data.Length, SocketFlags.None, Remote);
```

And your code should work.